# IoC: Create a Unity extension to override dependencies?

Tags: c#-4.0, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

By using Microsoft's Unity, I am able to override a dependency in the exact moment that I'm resolving an instance, for example:

```
var valueObjectThatOverridesAnyConfiguration = new object();

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.Resolve<ATypeWithConstructorArguments>(new DependencyOverride(typeof(object), valueObjectThatOverridesAnyPreviousConfiguration);
```

That will override any previous configuration on my UnityContainer and inject the instance I provided on the DependencyOverride.

Is there a way to specify it in a Container level ? Like an extension or something ? I don't want to do it at the resolve moment!

Thanks! Let me know if I'm being confuse to you, I'll provide more info.

Comment: I don't understand what is your goal  here. If you want to specify a container wide dependency override with the same constructor argument why don't you register your `ATypeWithConstructorArguments` type with that argument? So you don't need to override.

Comment: Cause I don't want to change the register every time my constructor dependencies changes.

What I'm really looking for is to say "When you find this requirement, provide this instance, no matter the rest of dependencies". So if I register the type I'll have to change the register every time my constructor changes.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is support for Auto-registration/Convention over Configuration. Unity doesn't supply that out of the box, while Castle Windsor, Autofac and StructureMap does...

Comment: Unity does not have conventions but an enhanced configuration engine is on the [wishlist](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general/suggestions/1672387-enhanced-configuration-for-unity) for Unity vNext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/278448). The part that sounds like your problem starts in the middle of the thread.

It allows you to do this

```
  var container = new UnityContainer();
  container.AddNewExtension<SemanticGroupExtension>();

  container.RegisterGroup<IVehicle, Car>("Car").Use<IWheel, CarWheel>().Use<IEngine, CarEngine>();
  container.RegisterGroup<IVehicle, Motorcycle>("Motorcycle").Use<IWheel, MotorcycleWheel>().Use<IEngine, MotorcycleEngine>();

  var car = container.Resolve<IVehicle>("Car");
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(car.Wheel, typeof(CarWheel));
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(car.Engine, typeof(CarEngine));

  var motorcycle = container.Resolve<IVehicle>("Motorcycle");
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(motorcycle.Wheel, typeof(MotorcycleWheel));
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(motorcycle.Engine, typeof(MotorcycleEngine));
```

The sources can be found [here](http://tecx.codeplex.com) inside the *TecX.Unity* project.